# Spider must return Request, BaseItem, dict or None, got 'set'

Tags: python, scrapy

I am trying to download images of all products from [here](http://www.shopclues.com/electronic-accessories-8/cameras-18/cameras-special.html?search=1&q1=camera). My spider looks like:

```py
from shopclues.items import ImgData
import scrapy

class multipleImages(scrapy.Spider):
     name='multipleImages'
     start_urls=['http://www.shopclues.com/electronic-accessories-8/cameras-18/cameras-special.html?search=1&q1=camera',]

     def parse (self, response):
        for url in response.css('div.products-grid div.grid-product):
                    yield {
                    ImgData(image_urls=[url.css('img::attr(src)').extract()])
                    }
```

and **items.py**:

```py
import scrapy
from scrapy.item import Item
class ShopcluesItem(scrapy.Item):
   # define the fields for your item here like:
   # name = scrapy.Field()
   pass

class ImgData(Item):
    image_urls=scrapy.Field()
    images=scrapy.Field()
```

But I get following error on running the spider:

```
2016-09-29 11:56:19 [scrapy] DEBUG: Crawled (200) <GET http://www.shopclues.com/robots.txt> (referer: None)
2016-09-29 11:56:20 [scrapy] DEBUG: Crawled (200) <GET http://www.shopclues.com/electronic-accessories-8/cameras-18/cameras-special.html?search=1&q1=camera> (referer: None)
2016-09-29 11:56:20 [scrapy] ERROR: Spider must return Request, BaseItem, dict or None, got 'set' in <GET http://www.shopclues.com/electronic-accessories-8/cameras-18/cameras-special.html?search=1&q1=camera>
2016-09-29 11:56:20 [scrapy] ERROR: Spider must return Request, BaseItem, dict or None, got 'set' in <GET http://www.shopclues.com/electronic-accessories-8/cameras-18/cameras-special.html?search=1&q1=camera>
2016-09-29 11:56:20 [scrapy] ERROR: Spider must return Request, BaseItem, dict or None, got 'set' in <GET http://www.shopclues.com/electronic-accessories-8/cameras-18/cameras-special.html?search=1&q1=camera>
2016-09-29 11:56:20 [scrapy] ERROR: Spider must return Request, BaseItem, dict or None, got 'set' in <GET http://www.shopclues.com/electronic-accessories-8/cameras-18/cameras-special.html?search=1&q1=camera>
2016-09-29 11:56:20 [scrapy] ERROR: Spider must return Request, BaseItem, dict or None, got 'set' in <GET http://www.shopclues.com/electronic-accessories-8/cameras-18/cameras-special.html?search=1&q1=camera>
```

What does this error means? What could be the possible reasons of the error?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Pass a list of urls to the pipeline.

```
 def parse (self, response):
     images = ImgData()
     images['image_urls']=[] 
     for url in response.css('div.products-grid div.grid-product'):
         images['image_urls'].append(url.css('img::attr(src)').extract_first())
     yield images
```

Answer (score 6):

`{}` is notation to define a set in python, or a dictionary. Depends on the values you provide inside of the curly brackets. If it's a list {a,b,c,d} <- that's a set, if it's key to value {a:b, c:d} <- that's a dict.

You yield a set in this line:

```
yield {
    ImgData(image_urls=[url.css('img::attr(src)').extract()])
}
```

I assume you want to yield a dictionary?

```
yield {
    'images': ImgData(image_urls=[url.css('img::attr(src)').extract()]),
}
```

Comment: I actually want to download all the images that are avilable under given path. I have done this for a single image by using `yield ImgData(image_urls=[url.css('img::attr(src)').extract_first()])` But using same for multiple images gives error like `Error processing {'image_urls': [[u'http://cdn.shopclues.com/images/thumbnails/25469/200/200/canoneos750dkitefs1855mmisstmdslr400x400imae77typaskcv7f14343509861444028422.jpg'` .